# How to add array to my html with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
var persons = ["Niko", "Jon", "Elica"];
```

I would like to display this array in my html.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please give an example of the expected HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got a working example for you:

```js
var persons = ["Niko", "Jon", "Elica"];;
for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++)
{
document.body.innerHTML += '<div >' + persons[i] + '</div>';
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Thankyou a lot! You just made my homework 0:)

Comment: You're welcome! Next time try to google some stuff first ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is iterate through the array like so:

```
persons.forEach(function(person) {
    //More code coming
}
```

And within that, create some list items and append them to the body:

```js
 

var persons = ["Niko", "Jon", "Elica"];

persons.forEach(function(person) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerText = person;
    document.body.append(item);
});
```

```html
<body></body>
```

And there you go!

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: snippet doesn't work xo

Answer (score 0):

```js
var persons = ["Niko", "Jon", "Elica"];
var d = document;

d.g = d.getElementById;
persons.forEach( (person) => {
     d.g("mylist").innerHTML += '<li >' + person + '</li>';
});
```

```html
<body>
<h1>My A-List</h1>
<UL id="mylist">

</ul>
</body>
```

This code iterates through the `persons` array to concatenate a string of HTML which is assigned to the innerHTML property of the unordered list. The [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)() of the array utilizes an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of the more usual anonymous function.

A more robust solution  would utilize the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) to create LI elements and append each to the unordered list with each array value being ascribed as the value of the text node for every LI element. The optimal way of doing so involves using an LI element's textContent property, as follows:

```js
var persons = ["Niko", "Jon", "Elica"];

var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

var ul = d.g("mylist");
var li = null;

persons.forEach( (person) => {
    let li=d.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.textContent= person;
});
```

```html
<body>
<h1>My Better List</h1>
<ul id="mylist">


</ul>
</body>
```

This solution, too, uses an arrow function expression rather than the expected anonymous function for the array's forEach method.

Note that per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

> Sometimes people use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an
>   element, but textContent has better performance because its value is
>   not parsed as HTML. Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS
>   attacks.